# Read multiple netCDF4 using Python 3

Tags: python, netcdf

I need to read a multiple netCDF4 files using python 3. The files are in different folder named 2019, 2018 with months and days. And the files have the same variables I use to read and plot it.

I can do that just for one file. How I can read all files and variable `IR` in all files in all folder?

```
path='/home/all/2019/03/25/Mmult_2.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset('/home/all/2019/03/25/Mmult_2.nc')
IR=nc.variables['IR'][:]
plt.pcolormesh(IR)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the glob.glob module to search all the nc-files in your sub-folder like this (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module):

```
import glob

list_of_paths = glob.glob('C:/Users/sam/Desktop/myfolder/**/*.nc', recursive=True)
```

Then, if there is a dimension in your netcdfs that is unlimited, you can open all the files in one line like this:

```
import netCDF4

nc = netCDF4.MFDataset(list_of_paths)
```

After this you will probably want to be carefull, because doing:

```
IR=nc.variables['IR'][:]
```

will load the 'IR'-data from ALL your nc-files into your memory at once, which could crash you computer. So it's probably better to load small parts at a time by replacing [:] with, for example, [0:2].

Comment: thanks u but what mean [0:2] my problem that i have a simple application wxpython when i have button this button for select file in directory netcdf file i want to open so after open i want plot it so i will try ... but please what mean [0:2] ? exist method to open  the file i want and plot it ?

Comment: i have question we can use loop for and loop for for variables keys ?

Comment: that is imformations about my variable IR in file netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int16 IR_108(ny, nx)
    
    Offset : radiance = offset + CN x slope: -10.456819486590666
    Slope : radiance = offset + CN x slope: 0.2050356762076601
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (3712, 3712)
filling on

Comment: when i do : `import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
list_of_paths = glob.glob('/home/all/2019/03/25/*.nc', recursive=True)nc = netCDF4.MFDataset(list_of_paths) IR=nc.variables['IR'][0:1]` i had error like : name 'nc' is not defined In [15]: nc = netCDF4.MFDataset(list_of_paths)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError: dataset /homm/all/msg04/all/2019/03/25/Mmulti_201903252000.nc does not have a aggregation dimension

Comment: ok then you'll have to use "netCDF4.Dataset" instead of "netCDF4.MFDataset" and load a single nc-file at a time. So you need to make a for-loop on the list_of_paths

Comment: when i do  `IR=nc.variables['IR'][0:1]` i have error like nc is not defined ?! so after `nc=netCDF4.Dataset(list_of_paths)` i need to make for-loop ? or what please exempl how can i make for loop ?! thank u

Comment: you have to loop over list_of_paths, so: for path in list_of_paths: nc = netCDF4.Dataset(path)

Comment: if the answer helped you, you can accept it as the correct answer please.

Comment: yes thank u ! please i have question what mean shape and range in netcdf4 ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend xarray. http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#reading-multi-file-datasets

```py
import xarray
xarray.open_mfdataset('my/files/*.nc', parallel=True)
```